# if condition always evaluating true

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

```
        if [[ ${fin[2]} -eq OK && ${fin[7]} -eq NA ]]
        then
                echo "<tr id="green">" >> /tmp/mailt.txt
        elif [[ ${fin[2]} -eq OK && ${fin[7]} -lt 0 ]]
        then
                echo "<tr id="yellow">" >> /tmp/mailt.txt
        elif [[ ${fin[2]} -ne OK && ${fin[7]} -eq NA && $currDate2 -gt $expectedFinishTimes ]]
        then
                echo "<tr id="red">" >> /tmp/mailt.txt
        elif [[ ${fin[2]} -ne OK && ${fin[7]} -eq NA && $currDate2 -lt $expectedFinishTimes ]]
        then
                echo "<tr id="white">" >> /tmp/mailt.txt
        fi
```

In the above, only first condition is evaluating to be true even when `${fin[2]}` is not equal to OK. What's wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The operators `-eq` and `-ne` are *arithmetic* operators for comparing *numerical* data.

What you want here is `==` and `!=`:

```
if [[ "${fin[2]}" == 'OK' ]] &&
   [[ "${fin[7]}" == 'NA' ]]; then
```

and

```
elif [[ "${fin[2]}" != 'OK' ]] &&
     [[ "${fin[7]}" == 'NA' ]] &&
     (( currDate2 < expectedFinishTimes )); then
```

(for example).

---

Also, be careful with your quoting and `echo`:

```
echo "<tr id="green">"
```

is better written as

```
echo '<tr id="green">'
```

The first will produce

```
<tr id=green>
```

while the second will produce

```
<tr id="green">
```

Comment: Note that the problem is caused by `-eq` and `-ne` implicitly causing their string operands to be recursively evaluated as variable names, meaning the arguments eventually reduce to 0 (unless you accidentally expand to the name of an actual integer variable). In other words, if neither `foo` nor `OK` are variable names, `[[ foo -eq OK ]]` reduces to `[[ 0 -eq 0 ]]`, which is true.